# Convert array of negative numbers in to array of possitives

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 var numbers = [
  1, 2, -2, 6, -5, 9, 1.02, 45, -69, 77, -12, 2, 8, -2, -4, 59, 7, -3,
];

function arrAbsoluteValues(arr) {
  arr = arr.map((s) => Math.abs(s));
}

console.log(arrAbsoluteValues(numbers));
```

I'm trying to get array that would convert all negative numbers into positive, but I'm getting undefined.

output I expect: [
1, 2, 2, 6, 5, 9, 1.02, 45, 69, 77, 12, 2, 8, 2, 4, 59, 7, 3,
]

Comment: That's because you're not `return`ing anything from your `arrAbsoluteValues` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to add `return` in `arrAbsoluteValues` function

```js
var numbers = [
  1, 2, -2, 6, -5, 9, 1.02, 45, -69, 77, -12, 2, 8, -2, -4, 59, 7, -3,
];

function arrAbsoluteValues(arr) {
  return arr.map((s) => Math.abs(s));
}

console.log(arrAbsoluteValues(numbers));
```

Comment: Yes, it does, it makes more sense, thanks for the help